# The procedure entry point _gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, mingw, codeblocks

I have installed Codeblocks 13.12 with MinGW and I try to run an OpenCV application. I compiled it with no problems but when I try to run it throws the following error:

```
The procedure entry point _gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll
```

I checked on stackoverflow questions with similar problems and everyone was pointing to copying the MinGW dll file to the application folder. I did that and then I had this error:

```
This application has failed to start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

So I copied that dll too. And then I had the following error:

```
This application has failed to start because libgcc_s_sjij-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I copied this dll too and then I had the first error about the missing **__gxx_personality_v0** entry point all over again.

Comment: is that an older opencv version with precompiled libs for mingw ?

Comment: @berak Yes I use OpenCV 2.3 with precompiled libs.

Comment: as @rubenvb said below, you need to use *exactly* the same toolchain, the opencv libs were built against. this is the main reason, why they stopped delivering prebuild libs lately. rebuilding them from src might be your best bet. and while you're at that, please update to 2.4.9. 2.3 is stone-age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an ABI incompatibility. You are linking code built with two different toolchains (one with dw2 exception handling and one with sjlj).

Either rebuild everything with the same toolchain, or find yourself a matching toolchain:

- [MinGW-w64 installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download) is located [here](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds). You can select various variants when you run it.
- Use [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/), which comes with a repository containing a variety of packages already compiled for you (including OpenCV). It comes with the pacman package manager (ported from Arch Linux). It provides a Unix shell environment for your convenience, but the toolchains can be used outside of the shell itself.

Comment: I used precompiled OpenCV libs and that was the cause of the error. I rebuilt the project with the .lib files and it asked for the tbb.dll. I copied it and it worked like a charm.